# SSIS package File enumerator empty when package is executed outside of visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, foreach, ssis, package

I have a SSIS package that i want to use in a job that populates a table from a flat file located on file system. Since it's a nightly delta file im using foreach enumerator for the file path and a variable for the file name. When i execute it from visual studio it works fine and the table gets populated with data. But when i execute it as an SQL Agent job or just run the package i get this warning message:

[image: empty file foreach enumerator]

And the table is not populated with data and I have also doubble checked that a file is in the directory.

Any ideas on what i can do to solve this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Permissions issue for the SQL Agent account and/or the Proxy you have created to run the SSIS packages

Comment: Take a peek at http://stackoverflow.com/a/16776763/181965

Comment: Thank you for your answers. That could be the reason. But the proxy I'm using has the same credentials as my Windows user which has read and write permission to the file system, so it shouldn't be any problems?

Comment: Local folders or a network drive? If network, are you accessing via UNC path `\\server\share\myFile.txt` or mapped drive letter `M:\myFile.txt`?

Comment: It's a network drive accessed through a mapped drive letter. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Highly probable that the mapped drive is the issue. Try swapping it out for a UNC path

Comment: You can use the Execute Process Task to add/remove drive letter mappings when the package begins - [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9064494/181965) HLGEM has a post on how they solved it but I'm not finding it via search

Comment: I tried using the UNC path but i still experience the same issue. I will try the other solution you proposed. Thank you!

Comment: Can you log on to the SQL Server with the Proxy account's credentials and navigate to the UNC path you are using from there?

Comment: Sigh... The problem was in the foreach enumerator folder. When I used 

Z:\Folder\FolderWithFiles

When i changed it to

Z:\Folder\FolderWithFiles\

It worked to execute the package outside of visual studio.

But now when i try to execute the job it just says

The job succeeded.  The Job was invoked by User Domain\User.  The last step to run was step 1 (SSIS Import). 

But nothinig happens in the table...

Comment: FINALLY. So the problem in the end was that the UNC path i tried was missing a directory. After adding the directory the job is successfull! Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the foreach enumerator folder. When I used

> Z:\Folder\FolderWithFiles

It didn't work. I then changed it to

> Z:\Folder\FolderWithFiles\

and it worked outside of visual studio (execution of the package).

When i then tried using the UNC path:

> \\Server.Domain\DomainFolder\Folder\FolderWithFiles\

It worked using a SQL Server Agent Job.

To summarize: Be sure that you have the correct path and directories on your file enumerator.

Answer (score 0):

*You must have 50 reputation to comment

Thank you so much.

```
"I then changed it to

    Z:\Folder\FolderWithFiles\

and it worked outside of visual studio (execution of the package)."
```

This comment helped me alot today.
The exact same package worked with Visual Studio 2013 and Server 2014 but i had trouble migrating it to Visual Studio 2019 with Server 2019